# How to set custom console banner for Play application via SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

When I run the command from terminal : `sbt run`

It logs on the console like this:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 1.8.0_362)
[info] loading global plugins from /.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /demo/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info]   __              __
[info]   \ \     ____   / /____ _ __  __
[info]    \ \   / __ \ / // __ `// / / /
[info]    / /  / /_/ // // /_/ // /_/ /
[info]   /_/  / .___//_/ \__,_/ \__, /
[info]       /_/               /____/
[info] 
[info] Version 2.8.18 running Java 1.8.0_362
[info] 
[info] Play is run entirely by the community. Please consider contributing and/or donating:
[info] https://www.playframework.com/sponsors
```

Now, I want to modify below default banner to a custom banner.

```
[info]   __              __
[info]   \ \     ____   / /____ _ __  __
[info]    \ \   / __ \ / // __ `// / / /
[info]    / /  / /_/ // // /_/ // /_/ /
[info]   /_/  / .___//_/ \__,_/ \__, /
[info]       /_/               /____/
[info]
```

Is it even possible to modify? If yes, then please mention on how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override [`onLoadMessage`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/f5e08386e19eb615e395b06cb7a9917f5533d8ba/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L93) key in the **build.sbt** of your project:

```
import play.sbt.Colors

onLoadMessage := {
 """|  __              __
    |  \ \     ____   / /____ _ __  __
    |   \ \   / __ \ / // __ `// / / /
    |   / /  / /_/ // // /_/ // /_/ /
    |  /_/  / .___//_/ \__,_/ \__, /
    |      /_/               /____/
    |""".stripMargin.linesIterator.map(Colors.green(_)).mkString("\n")
}
```

If you want a custom banner for e.g. your contributors, personally I prefer to use [sbt-welcome](https://github.com/reibitto/sbt-welcome) to provide users with some nice welcome message, useful tasks and hints how to start working with the code. It will set up `onLoadMessage` using some structured format.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. It worked for me. Therefore, I'm upvoting and accepting your answer as `onLoadMessage` did the trick. Today, I've learnt something new. :)

Answer (score 2):

That message, comes from the [Play plugin for sbt](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/BuildOverview#Play-plugin-for-sbt-(/project/plugins.sbt)). You can find that message in the [playframework repo](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.20/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L73)

```scala
  // Settings for a Play service (not a web project)
  lazy val serviceSettings = Seq[Setting[_]](
    onLoadMessage := {
      val javaVersion = sys.props("java.specification.version")
      """|  __              __
         |  \ \     ____   / /____ _ __  __
         |   \ \   / __ \ / // __ `// / / /
         |   / /  / /_/ // // /_/ // /_/ /
         |  /_/  / .___//_/ \__,_/ \__, /
         |      /_/               /____/
         |""".stripMargin.linesIterator.map(Colors.green(_)).mkString("\n") +
        s"""|
            |
            |Version ${play.core.PlayVersion.current} running Java ${System.getProperty("java.version")}
            |
            |${Colors.bold(
             "Play is run entirely by the community. Please consider contributing and/or donating:"
           )}
            |https://www.playframework.com/sponsors
            |
            |""".stripMargin +
        (if (javaVersion == "17")
           s"""Running Play on Java ${sys.props("java.specification.version")} is experimental. Tweaks are necessary:
              |https://github.com/playframework/playframework/releases/2.8.15
              |
              |""".stripMargin
         else if (javaVersion != "1.8" && javaVersion != "11")
           s"""!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
              |  Java version is ${sys
               .props("java.specification.version")}. Play supports only 8, 11 and, experimentally, 17.
              |!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
              |
              |""".stripMargin
         else "")
    }
```

If you look for `PlaySettings.serviceSettings` you wil be able to find that property used in the definition of the [AutoPlugin class for Play](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.20/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/Play.scala#L28)

```scala
object PlayService extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = JavaServerAppPackaging
  val autoImport        = PlayImport

  override def globalSettings  = PlaySettings.serviceGlobalSettings
  override def projectSettings = PlaySettings.serviceSettings
}
```

then you can find that the `PlayPlugin` that you have to be enabled in the project definition in the `build.sbt` file extends `PlayService`

```scala
object PlayScala extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires        = PlayWeb
  override def projectSettings = PlaySettings.defaultScalaSettings
}
```

You have different approaches.

- override the value of `onLoadMessage`

```scala
import play.sbt.Colors

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "play-with-dino-logo",
    onLoadMessage := {
      """
        |                       __
        |                      / _)
        |             _.----._/ /
        |            /         /
        |         __/ (  | (  |
        |        /__.-'|_|--|_|
                      """
        .stripMargin
        .linesIterator
        .map(Colors.blue(_))
        .mkString("\n")
    }
  ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

once you start your play app, you will see the new message

[image: dino logo]

- another approach could be to create your own [sbt plugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html) extending the play plugin and override the `onLoadMessage`. If you have more than one project, that will let you change the message in one place if you want that all of them have the same message each time they start.

Comment: `serviceSettings` is a *collection* of overrides. The *key* which is displaying the message is `onLoadMessage`. By overriding it OP should be able to change the behavior.

Comment: I couldn't remember how to do the override in the settings. I will update my answer. Thanks